# Move files listed in csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I have been trying to use the following code to move files that are listed in a csv list. But at most it will copy the last file in the list but not the rest.
I keep hitting this wall with every example I have seen listed what am I doing wrong?

My CVS list will have a list like:

```
12355,12355.jpg
```

Here's my code

```
import os
import shutil
import csv
keys={}
with open('shuttle_image.csv', 'r') as f:
 reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
 for rowDict in reader:
    keys[rowDict[0]] = rowDict[1]
    print (rowDict)

dir_src = 'C:\\Users\\Willie\\Desktop\\Suppliers Dropship\\hunting\\'
dir_dst = 'C:\\image\\' 
for file in os.listdir(dir_src):
    src_file = os.path.join(dir_src, file)
    dst_file = os.path.join(dir_dst, file)
    if file in rowDict[1]:
        shutil.move(src_file, dst_file)
```

Comment: I assume rowDict[1] contains the last filename only. Have you check what rowDict contains? Why use rowDict instead of the dictionary keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think doing something like this will work (untested):

```
import os
import shutil
import csv

keys={}
with open('shuttle_image.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for rowDict in reader:
       keys[rowDict[0]] = rowDict[1]
       print(rowDict)  # if desired

valid_files = set(keys.values())  # file names found in csv
dir_src = 'C:\\Users\\Willie\\Desktop\\Suppliers Dropship\\hunting\\'
dir_dst = 'C:\\image\\'
for file in os.listdir(dir_src):
    if file in valid_files:
        src_file = os.path.join(dir_src, file)
        dst_file = os.path.join(dir_dst, file)
        shutil.move(src_file, dst_file)
```

As an optimization, unless you need the `keys` dictionary for other processing, you could change the first part so it just creates the `valid_files` set variable used in the second `for` loop:

```
valid_files = set()  # empty set
with open('shuttle_image.csv', 'r') as f:
    for rowDict in csv.reader(f, delimiter=','):
       valid_files |= {rowDict[1]}  # add file name to set
       print(rowDict)  # if desired
```

Comment: Thank You Martin, It does work. May I ask what would be the best way to use a error check to list any files that was not found or not moved

Comment: You're welcome. One simple way would be to _remove_ each file name from `valid_files` after a successful call to `shutil.move()` by using a `valid_files -= {file}` statement. Then, after the moving `for` loop ends, you can check if anything is left in it: i.e `if valid_files:`, `print('some files not found or moved')`. You also need to put the `shutil.move()` call in a `try`/`except shutil.Error:` block so any copy errors don't cause your script to terminate when one occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's only the last file that could be copied (if it was) is because in this line:

```
     if file in rowDict[1]:
```

you are referencing `rowDict` outside of the first for-loop. So at that execution moment, it contains the last value of this loop.

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do you could try something like this (untested code):

```
import os
import shutil
import csv

dir_src = 'C:\\Users\\Willie\\Desktop\\Suppliers Dropship\\hunting\\'
dir_dst = 'C:\\image\\' 

with open('shuttle_image.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
    for rowDict in reader:
        id, filename = rowDict
        src_file = os.path.join(dir_src, filename)
        if os.path.exists(src_file):
            shutil.move(src_file, dir_dst)
```

So instead of:

1. Constructing a dictionary with all the values in your CSV file
2. Somehow check for every file in your source directory that it is included in your dictionary (which is what I interpreted you were trying to do)

   - And move it if it does.

You could:

1. For every file extracted from your CSV, check that it exists in your source directory.

   - If it does, you move it to the destination directory.

Is that what you were trying to do ?

[And if the filename stays the same, you only need to specify the destination directory for the second argument of shutil.move()]